# Why Schottky diode’s cut in voltage is less and the reverse saturation current is more than normal P-N junction diode?

Tags: diodes, semiconductors, schottky

I want to know how do we achieve lower forward voltage as much as 0.2-0.3 volt in schottky diodes.

Comment: Read a book about semiconductors and learn how a PN junction works and what determines its forward voltage. Then study the Metal-to-Semiconductor junction (because that is what a Schottky diode is).

Comment: quick answer: a schottky diode is P doped semiconductor connected to bare wire, not a complete P-N junction.

Comment: @FakeMoustache I have read about both but could not understand the reason for it.

Comment: Look up and compare the band diagram for both junction types. If that doesn't clarify it for you, you need to better understand the band diagram because that explains the difference.

Comment: This is not even *necessarily* true. For example, SiC Schottky diodes have a relatively high Vf and low reverse leakage but are really, really fast.

Answer (score 2):

You can look up the details, so I'll be brief and describe it only at a high level.

"Normal" diodes are a full semiconductor junction, made of P and N doped semiconductors.

Schottky diodes are sortof half a junction.  They are a semiconductor and a metal.  This as only about half the forward drop.  It also has more reverse leakage.  The metal-semiconductor junction isn't as good at blocking flow in reverse as a semiconductor-semiconductor junction.